# How to hide the cursor when its idle and hovering over a playing video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have looked for a type of response here and other places, that may be applicable to solving my problem but all I get is CSS and "no just don't bad user experience"... I don't want to hide the cursor immediately when over a element, or frick with peoples experience.

I just want to make it a better experience for when someone mouse is idle (for certain amount of time) over a playing video (like YouTube for example) the cursor goes away ***temporarily*** and ***comes back** if the user moves his/her mouse.

And what I've tried for my own with some knowledge I know down below

```js
let vidod = document.getElementById("vidof");

vidod.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = "none";
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", et => {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });
    }, 3500);
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
}
```

```html
<video id="vidof" autoplay>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
</video>
```

BUT that doesn't work... I don't know what to do now, or how to make it work!

> EDIT: The problem was a syntax error as **[Dick Larsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254228/dick-larsson)** pointed out

> And yes thank you **[Ali Kianoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6393585/ali-kianoor)** and **[D. Seah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808826/d-seah)**, those were good answers as well. And worked really well. and don't worry ALL were sweet and simple answers **[Ali Kianoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6393585/ali-kianoor)** keep up the simple yet efficient code... and of course another thanks to **[D. Seah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808826/d-seah)** thats a good one... for i would never thought to all that, yet simple. Thank You!

***And sorry I like all answers I get, I have been coding three years now(since 2018) but I'm still learning, and all answers are ones I can also learn from!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the "Identity operator" === to assign a value.

```
document.body.style.cursor === "none"
```

You should assign the value "none" like this

```
document.body.style.cursor = "none"
```

The same goes for
document.body.style.cursor === "default";

Comment: Also thanks for letting me know my code wasn't bad, but just a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

i think it is better to do it in this way. https://jsfiddle.net/56emzjws/3/

```js
const vidod = document.getElementById("vidof");

vidod.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  // clear the timer if it is set when the mouse move
  const timer = vidod.getAttribute("timer");
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    vidod.setAttribute("timer", "");
  }

  # set timeout to wait of idle time
  const t = setTimeout(() => {
    vidod.setAttribute("timer", "");
    vidod.classList.add("hide-cursor");
  }, 3500);
  vidod.setAttribute("timer", t);

  vidod.classList.remove("hide-cursor");
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works if I ever need to to use it this I will.
All you of your guys answers are working and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a CSS class like this one I made for you 'hideCursor'.

```js
let vidod = document.getElementById("vidof");

vidod.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = "none";
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", et => {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });
    }, 3500);
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
}

.hideCursor {cursor: none;}
```

```html
<video id="vidof" autoplay>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I get that I can add a class so that it hides, but I still need to re-show it once its gone and they move the mouse.

Comment: I got it, I changed the code. please check it

Comment: Thanks that works if I ever need to to use it this I will.
All you of your guys answers are working and helpful!